# Manipulate feature maps while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction

**In summary,** similar to the Faster-RCNN and Mask-RCNN papers that perform ROI pooling on the feature maps, I want to apply some changes to the feature maps of the last convolutional layer of VGG19. First, I want to divide the feature maps to 4 equal parts and put them on top of each other. Then, feed it to a fully-connected layer.

**What I have:**
I am using the example at https://github.com/sugi-chan/fgo-multi-task-keras/blob/master/fgo_multiclass.ipynb

based on https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer, I need to construct the model first:

```
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x)
intermediate_layer_model.compile(loss=loss_list, optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics=test_metrics)
```

**Problem with this suggestion:** I want to extract the feature map and do some process on it while continuing the training phase on the main model (That is called `multi_model()` in the code I referenced above). However, this suggestion constructs the model with features as its output.

Another thing is that I have seen the RoIAlignPooling layer code at https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py but it is hard for me to use it in an easy example like mnist dataset. I appreciate your comments, codes, links to tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want inside a layer as long as the procedures you write are differentiable.

You can create a [custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and in that layer use [tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf) to do whatever you want. You just need to do every operation using a TensorFlow function. This is sometimes very hard to do since you deal only with tensors operations.
Before using a tensor operation be sure that it is differentiable. For instance `tf.multiply` is differentiable, `tf.histogram_fixed_width` is not.

In your case, this new layer would be the input of the dense layer.

Comment: could you please tell whether tf.keras.layers.Discretization is differentiable or not? Is it possible to use it to manipulate feature maps before feeding them to the next layer ?